# What to do if OP self-answers their own bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, self-answer

I was going through the Help and Improvement queue, and found [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58502413/7431860) It's a bit difficult to read, includes links to images instead of the code, and seems to be asking for someone else to write the software for him. Ordinarily I'd flag this question to be closed, but in this case, OP has self-answered the question with what appears to be a working solution.

What do I do in this situation?

Comment: If it's a bad question, you can downvote it or try to improve it. If it's not useful to others, you can vote to close it. Being self-answered doesn't absolve a question of being bad.

Comment: Would it be ironic if he answered his own question?

Comment: Treat it like *any other bad question*. It really doesn't matter who answered a question here, self-answering doesn't exempt the question from being moderated.

Comment: Alright, thank you all for the input; if I think I can help the question, I'll edit it, and if not, I'll vote to close it.

Comment: @NickReed dont loose to much of your time with the question. With the meta effect, I am confident to say that the question is going to be closed soon.

Comment: Personally I downvote all answers to a question I think should be deleted as it makes it more likely the system will automatically delete the questince once it is closed and has a few down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Treat it like any other bad question. It really doesn't matter who answered a question here, self-answering doesn't exempt the question from being moderated.

Yes this comment from Martijn Pieters♦ is your answer. You just have to considerer that the questioner and the answerer are two different beings. Moderate the question like any other question and moderate the answer as any other answer.

Your question could be basically the same as "What to do if someone answer a bad question?"